# Is the gradient vector of a function the derivative of the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is the gradient vector the derivative of any function?

I was wondering this because this works with a function of one variable.

Comment: No, the good definition of 'derivative' for multiple variables is that of [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables). It is not the gradient. **Edit:** Well, in a sense the gradient is the differential.

Comment: But wouldn't it work if you took the magnitude of the gradient by using the the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: The gradient is actually the directional derivative in the direction of greatest increase of the function.  The derivative needs to be more general than that.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth distinguishing them slightly. The derivative of a function $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ at a point $p \in U$ is a linear map $Df_p : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$. We can identify the gradient of $f$ with $D_p$, if everything exists, by

$$Df_p(v) = \langle \nabla f(p), v\rangle$$

Equivalently, $Df_p$ is a co-tangent vector, i.e., a member of the set of linear maps acting on $T_p$, the vector space of tangent vectors at $p$: i.e., $Df_p = \langle \nabla f(p), \cdot \rangle : T_p \to \mathbb{R}$. This formalism is helpful when we want to generalize from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to manifolds.